# How to move site-package from folder Python37 to folder Python310?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Recently, in I download and install Python 3.10, then uninstall Python 3.7 in win10.However, when I want to import some modules in script, it shows there is no modules. After checking, I found all modules are still saved in `C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37`
So if I want to use them, just `copy/paste` them into `Python310`? Need I change other things, like classpath...

If not, what should I do? download from Internet again?

Comment: I didn't found update option when I install Python3.10...

Comment: just download again, the pure python libraries are easy to install. for those require compilation, chances are high it won't work even you copy it elsewhere.

Comment: @LeiYang really funny but my package is over 5g now...

Comment: then just try copy it, at risk! you may need remove version specific folders such as `__pycache__`. i think the worse case is you find something not working, then remove that lib and reinstall again. i believe some libs still work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't copy site `site-packages` dir from one version of Python to another - at best you'll get undefined behaviour. The appropriate way of getting the modules you want from v3.7 to v3.10 is to run `pip list` from the v3.7 installation to see what you have installed, then `pip freeze` to write that to a file, and finally use the v3.10 pip to install from the file that you wrote the list to.

This way you will get the modules built with and for v3.10.

Comment: so I have to install them all again?

Comment: Yes, you have to install them all again